# html5 datalist and input - how to select the complete list value when pressing tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to use html5 datalist in my program (angularjs) because I want the user to have the possibility to enter an option which is not in the list.

However, what I have noted so far is, when using the html5 Datalist, you loose the possibility of choosing an item in the list by just writing part of the text and pressing tab. What happens is the input element retains just what you typed and not the complete item in the list.

Is there a way to make Datalist+Input to choose the **whole** item in the list by just typing part of it and pressing tab??

Many thanks for your help and bye ...

Comment: the question is not clear.Can you create a demo and show the problem?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, I think it is not exactly about my code but about the behavior of Input+Datalist. Please open this MDN web page for Datalist:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist, and try the example; if you type just "choco" and press Tab, the Input element is not going to have "chocolate", what I need,  but "choco". Could you please open the page and try it. Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

Well I just ended up using *selectize.js* in my project.

This is a jquery plugin that can use an (html) Input to allow the user to select an option from a list, but **also** permits the user to type a new option (which is not in the list). This is exactly what I wanted.

There is a great post about using the plugin in Medium:

[Using Selectize.js to Make Your Forms Better](https://medium.com/@tchryssos/using-selectize-js-to-make-your-forms-better-523e86e356ce)

Many thanks and bye ...